# VSInstr inject own code

Tags: c#, .net, instrumentation

I'm looking for a way of instrumenting a binary with my own functions. Basically, insert a call to a function before each method in the binary file.

1. Is it possible to do this with VSInstr.exe or another instrumentation tool for .NET?
2. If 1 is not possible: how can I implement my instrumentation tool? Are there any open source tools to use as starting point?

Regards,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CCI](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) or [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) can do such things